# Validation rule in sql and access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a validation rule but using SQL in Access. I am very new to this. I know how to do it in regular Access design view, but don't know how to do it when using the create table command. So far I have,

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
    CustomerName TEXT (20),
    Gender TEXT (10),
    FavoriteFood TEXT (20)
);
```

Would like to add a validation rule to gender for just male/female/notknown.

Comment: I think validation rule is not part of MS Jet

Answer (score 3):

A field's Validation Rule is a `DAO.TableDef` property which can't be created using Access SQL.

If you want to use Access SQL for something similar, use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`. This statement will limit `Gender` values to male, female, or unknown.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
    CustomerName TEXT (20),
    Gender TEXT (10) NOT NULL,
    FavoriteFood TEXT (20),
    CONSTRAINT allowed_genders CHECK
        (
            Gender IN ('male','female','unknown')
        )
);
```

Note a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` can only be used in Access SQL when executed from ADO.  I executed that statement with `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`, which is an ADO method.

Some consequences of this approach may make it unacceptable to you ...

1. The constraint is not visible in table Design View.
2. When the constraint is violated, the error message does not appear until you attempt to save the record.
3. And the error message is based on the constraint name ... which is not very user-friendly in this case.
4. Because of the constraint, you can not delete the table from the Access UI; you would have to first execute `DROP CONSTRAINT allowed_genders` and then delete the table, or execute `DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS` which will discard both the table and constraint at the same time.

You might prefer to create a simpler version of the table and then set the Validation Rule with DAO.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("CUSTOMERS")
tdf.Fields("Gender").ValidationRule = "IN ('male','female','unknown')"
tdf.Fields("Gender").ValidationText = "Gender must be male, female, or unknown"
```

Notes:

1. The DAO methods allow you to also include a user-friendly Validation Text message.
2. When the Validation Rule is violated, Access will display the error message as soon as you attempt to move to the next field.

Finally yet another approach would be to create a lookup table which contains your allowed `Gender` values, make `CUSTOMERS.Gender` a foreign key to that lookup field, and enforce referential integrity.

Any of those 3 approaches might fit your situation; choose whichever seems to fit best.  :-)

Comment: Can the constraint name not be a bracketed multi-word phrase? E.g., `constraint [Gender must be male, female, or unknown]`?

Comment: Also I want to point out that the constraint approach is more portable to other DBMs.

Comment: @Yawar Yes, and the error message displayed when that constraint is violated is rather unwieldy: *"One or more values are prohibited by the validation rule 'Gender must be male, female, or unknown' set for 'CUSTOMERS'.  Enter a value that the expression for this field can accept."*  If the error message will be the deciding factor, I would prefer the Validation Text, *"Gender must be male, female, or unknown"*, because it's simple, direct, and concise.

Comment: What happens if you set the constraint in SQL and then _also_ set the field validation text in VBA? Actually, that sounds interesting enough to try out.

Comment: I wondered about that, too, but wasn't motivated enough to find out.  I'll guess the DAO Validation Rule, since it triggers earlier, would make the constraint superfluous.  Oops --- you said Validation *Text*.  But I don't think Validation Text would work without Validation Rule.