# Using SSMA to convert from Access to SQL, scripting the fixes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using SSMA to convert from an Access db to a SQL 2019 DB.

There are some things I need to fix in the access DB so I am trying to figure out whether or not these things can be done via a query in access or you have to use the goofy UI and do everything manually.

So I had a couple of questions about queries in Microsoft Access:

Can you modify the 'required' attribute on a column within a table by using a query?
Can you configure Index (dupes) on a column by using a query?
Can you change validation rules using a query?
Can you create/delete relationships using a query?
Can you change the field length of a column by using a query?

Any examples of any of these would be helpful, when I google for ms access related things all of the content is either related to Access 2007/2010 or its very UI heavy rather than Query heavy.

I am trying to script this because I may have to do this migration several times.

Update: I was able to get most of what i needed figured out..

```
ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN Type CHECK(In ("I","U","") Or Is Null);
```

Still havent found a way to change the 'ValidationRule'.. trying to change it to

In ("I","U","") Or Is Null

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Data Definition Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/data-definition-language) section of the [MS Access SQL Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference), specifically the [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) statement, which will cover the majority of your questions.

For example, in response to:

> Can you change the field length of a column by using a query?

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ALTER COLUMN Field1 TEXT(100)
```

The above will change the data type of the field `Field1` within table `Table1` to a text field accommodating 100 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint in the right direction, I was able to figure out all of the requirements except for this....ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN Type CHECK(In ("I","U","") Or Is Null); Basically I am just trying to set the 'ValidationRule' to ("I","U","") Or Is Null)

Comment: In response to your last question, you may wish to refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22468351/7531598).