# Set the Validation Rule of a column in a Microsoft Access database, in .NET

Tags: ms-access, jet, .net-1.1

After adding a new column to a table in a Microsoft Access database, how can you set its *Validation Rule* and *Validation Text*?

My current workaround is a check constraint on the table.

The code uses `System.Data.OleDb` classes from .NET Framework 1.1, and the database engine is Microsoft Jet 4.0 (it is a very old application).

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467737/validation-rule-in-sql-and-access

Comment: @jbud Thank you. Can you access DAO from .NET?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jet DAO if you add the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" COM reference to your .NET project. Then you can do something like this:

```cs
var dbEngine = new DAO.DBEngine();
DAO.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb");
DAO.TableDef tbd = db.TableDefs["rule"];
DAO.Field fld = tbd.Fields["rule_number"];
fld.ValidationRule = "<> 6";
fld.ValidationText = "There is NO rule 6!";
db.Close();
```